# How to retrieve value from Storage and user it somewhere else in Ionic 2

Tags: ionic-framework, local-storage, ionic2

I am new to Ionic 2 and Promises and having some issues.

My Ionic 2 app saves an auth_token to the local storage:

```
this.storage.set('auth_token', auth_token);
```

Then later in my secured component I want to check if a token is set, but I don't know how to do this.

I tried this:

```
authenticate() {
    var auth_token = this.storage.get('auth_token').then((val) => {
        return val;
    });
  }
```

Then from somewhere else I called:

```
console.log(this.auth.authenticate);
```

But it won't work, it just returns the function itself.

How do I return the token from my authenticate method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check [here](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_promises.html) for chaining of promises.

In your `authenticate()` function return the original promise call and use then in the function in the other location

```
authenticate() {
    return this.storage.get('auth_token').then((val) => {
       return val;
    });
  }
```

When caling authenticate...

```
this.auth.authenticate().then((val)=>{
  console.log(val);
 }).catch(error=>{
   //handle error
 });
```

Comment: Thanks! Can I somehow put to parts together so that in my components I just have to call this.auth.getToken() to get the token?

Comment: authenticate() will be in your auth provider.. You can inject auth in a component and take the value as I have put in the answer

Answer (score 2):

You just want to check or do you need to return it?

If it's only checking you can do this:

```
authenticate() {
  this.storage.get('auth_token').then((val) => {
   if(val){ ... } // or console.log it if it's just what you need.
  }
}
```

If you need to return, create a promise like this:

```
authenticate = (): Promise<{exists: boolean, auth: any}> =>{
  return new Promise<{exists: boolean, auth: any}>(res =>{
    this.storage.get('auth_token').then((val) => {
      if(val){
        res({exists: true, auth: val});
      } else {
        res({exists: false, auth: val});
      }
    }
  })
}
```

and later call `authenticate().then(res =>{})` and access the object returned in res.

### EDIT

As commented by Suraj and tested now, it doesn't need to be encapsulated inside a new promise, so if you need to return it just use the method Suraj suggested.

Comment: just curious..is it really required to encapsulate in a new promise?

Comment: if he wants to use authenticate() method with promises i believe he needs to. Never tested the method you used, will do this now to see if it's better. At least it's more clean